# MikTeX's new file system

Tags: miktex

I went to the MikTeX github site to find out why my manuals are disappearing every time I update a package.  The explanation wasn't entirely obvious, but I eventually figured out that the packages (some of them) have been split into three separate packages, for example `pgfplots`, `pgfplots__doc` and `pgfplots__source`.

So I went through the entire list of packages and installed the __doc version of every package I have installed (admin).  My hope is that when **these** are updated the manuals will be updated too.

The problem is that only a few of the packages have __doc versions, so it looks like I will have to repeat this process every time I update my packages.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I think John meant documentation, not documents. The new miktex split means that at the first update after the split the documentation is no longer installed.

Comment: I changed "documents" to "manuals" to clarify the problem.

Comment: Related/of interest: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/844. It is my understanding that `<pkg>__doc` would be updated alongside `<pkg>`. So once you have both installed (and both are installed in matching versions, which could be ensured by updating properly in case the two packages were not installed at the same time) you should be good. Since this split is only recent you will however observe that whenever a package that was packaged before the split is updated its documentation goes missing, because `<pkg>__doc` currently has to be installed manually. ...

Comment: ... But maybe that will change following the discussion in the linked GitHub issue.

Comment: I just noticed the Documentation button.   This is only useful if you find a missing manual and want to add it back.  It doesn't correlate installed packages with uninstalled documents.